# Have we seen any hints to the existence of snake people (sneople) within the government in Steven Universe?

Tags: steven-universe

One of [Ronaldo's](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Ronaldo_Fryman) conspiracy theories involve snake-people ("sneople") attempting to erode the government and take over the planet.  However, nearly every other conspiracy Ronaldo has stated within the show *has been right*.

[image: Sneople]

Moreover, the government in Steven Universe has placed a Gem and *a snake cut into pieces* on the dollar bill but thus far I have seen nothing to suggest that the sneople even exist, let alone that they are within the government.

[image: Dollar]

Is there any evidence of Snake-People and, if so, is there any evidence of them controlling the government in Steven Universe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Only what Ronaldo has shown us in that episode

The only evidence of sneople this far is what Ronaldo shows us in ["Keep Beach City Weird"](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_Beach_City_Weird_(episode)/Transcript): the bill and whatever is on the board where Ronaldo tracks the conspiracy by hanging up newspaper clippings of suspected sightings etc.:

[image]

(Apparently, the sneople are responsible for fish pizza.)

I figured it might be natural for the show to make a sneople comment in regards to Onion, seeing there was a rumour in ["Marble Madness"](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Marble_Madness/Transcript) that he is not human and, on top of that, he has a pet snake:

[image]

But the show never linked these two things (so far).

**I'm afraid the only sneople evidence is what Ronaldo has decided to show us.**

Comment: Ronaldo *was* right about the Great Diamond Authority, though. He even said that the world was controlled by polymorphic rocks taking on human shapes, which was, well…kind of true. Theory: the apparent broken snake on the bill is another Gem-related element. Further theory: a shattered Diamond?

Comment: @Adamant Never mind his foreshadowing of the Zoo. "Wait, so the hand **wasn't here to snatch up humans for a human zoo**, or interfere with our subsidized Beach City wind farm, or thaw out the cryogenically frozen pets of the one percent?!"

Comment: *Apparently, the sneople are responsible for fish pizza.* Yes, and who is now the mayor of Beach City? *Nanefua Pizza!* Wake *up*, sheeple! ;-D